# Python: How to properly apply OOP in the bouncing ball code

Tags: python, oop, attributes

I'm trying to apply OOP in this bouncing ball code in order to have multiple balls bouncing around the screen. The objective of this code is to create a method called settings, which controls all the settings for the screen and the bouncing behaviour of multiple balls, under the class Ball. However, I keep on getting errors related to attributes (e.g., speed). I'm new to OOP in Python so your help will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
import pygame
import random
import sys

pygame.init()

class Ball:
    def __init__(self, X, Y):
        self.velocity = [1,1]
        self.ball_image = pygame.image.load ("ball.jpg")
        self.ball_boundary = self.ball_image.get_rect ()
        self.black = [0,0,0]
        self.width = 800
        self.height = 600
        self.num = 8
        self.X = random.randint(0, self.width)
        self.Y = random.randint(0, self.height)

    def settings(self):
        #X = random.randint(0, self.width)
        #Y = random.randint(0, self.height)
        clock = pygame.time.Clock()
        size = self.width, self.height
        screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
        ball_boundary = self.ball_image.get_rect()
        speed = self.velocity
        pic = self.ball_image
        pygame.display.set_caption("Balls")
        num_balls = self.num
        ball_list = []

        for i in range(num_balls):
           ball_list.append( Ball(random.randint(10, self.width-10),random.randint(10, self.height-10)) )

        while 1:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    sys.exit(0)

            screen.fill(self.black)
            for balls in ball_list:
                if balls.ball_boundary.left < 0 or balls.ball_boundary.right > self.width:
                    balls.speed[0] = -balls.speed[0]
                if balls.ball_boundary.top < 0 or balls.ball_boundary.bottom > self.height:
                    balls.speed[1] = -balls.speed[1]
                balls.ball_boundary = balls.ball_boundary.move (self.velocity)
                screen.blit (balls.ball_image, balls.ball_boundary)
            pygame.display.flip()

play = Ball(random.randint(0, 800), random.randint(0, 600))

play.settings()
```

Comment: If you are having errors, you should say what they are and show the full traceback.

Comment: Traceback: 
AttributeError: Ball instance has no attribute 'speed'

Comment: That's not the full traceback. But it's at least clear that balls don't have a `speed` attribute, they have a `velocity` attribute.